# does not name a type error (using global class)

Tags: c++

I have to make my class global (know it is not a good style, but I'd like to use my class in other functions too).

After compiling I got following: error: ‘Test_Class’ does not name a type.

Here is the code:

main.cpp:

```
#include "class_header.h" 
#include "header.h"
Test_Class Test1, Test2, Test3;

int main(){

}
```

class_header.h:

```
#ifndef CLASS_HEADER_H
#define CLASS_HEADER_H

class Test_Class {
public:
    int get_a() const;
    int get_b() const;
private:
    int test_a;
    int test_b;
    int test_c;
};

#endif // CLASS_HEADER
```

header.h:

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

extern Test_Class Test1, Test2, Test3;

void test_source(int a, int b);

#endif // HEADER_H
```

source.cpp:

```
 #include "header.h"

 void test_source(int a, int b){

 }
```

I defined the class in main, so I don't understand the error message. Thanks for help.

Comment: When you compile `source.cpp`, how does the compiler know what `Test_Class` is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line `extern Test_Class Test1, Test2, Test3;` in `header.h` requires the declaration of `Test_Class`: which is not seen when `source.cpp` is compiled.

One remedy would be to `#include class_header.h` at the very start of `source.cpp`.

Comment: In my opinion, it would be better to include `class_header.h` in `header.h` instead. After all, any file that includes `header.h` will need the definitions in `class_header.h`.

Comment: Yes, that would be nice. Why not put as an answer? You could also drop the scheme altogether and use std::unique_ptr.

Comment: @user2079303 that is exactly what I have proposed. :)

Comment: @Bathsheba, I didn't post it as an answer because it's identical to yours except for one detail. I thought that commenting on your answer would be more productive. Then again, if you disagree with my opinion, a separate answer would be apt. The answer exists now, so it souldn't matter.

Comment: For me, the missing answer is one using pointers and forward declarations.

Answer (score 3):

Your file `header.h` strongly depend on the `class_header.h` since you use the Test_Class class.
You should therefor include the `class_header.h` inside the `header.h` file.

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#include class_header.h

extern Test_Class Test1, Test2, Test3;

void test_source(int a, int b);

#endif // HEADER_H
```

Any other solution would be fragile to change. An any client will have issue if they don't layout the header file in the right order.

You can also simplify your main.cpp

```
#include "header.h"
Test_Class Test1, Test2, Test3;

int main(){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include header `class_header.h:`in module `source.cpp:` before header `header.h:`. Otherwise the compiler does not know what means `Test_Class` in declaration

```
extern Test_Class Test1, Test2, Test3;
```

Or you should write the declaration the following way

```
extern class Test_Class Test1, Test2, Test3;
```

Comment: if Test1 Test2 and Test3 are intern object is ok but any attempt to access method or member of those object it will not work.

Comment: @mathk: That's rather obvious. This is my preferred solution as it limits the number of `#include`s in headers.

Comment: @Bathsheba It is so-called elaborated type name. If you need only the declaratio of a class then you may use its elaborated type name.